# Simple Moderation Model - Including a predictor of moderating variable

Tags: regression, structural-equation-modeling, interaction

I have a moderation model that I am specifying using SEM whereby X, M and X*M predict Y. However, I have a hypothesis that the moderator, M is predicted by another variable, Z.

i.e.

M = B01 + Z*a1

Y = B02 + X*b1 + M*b2 + (X*M)*b3

Is this possible (statistically)? I have not seen a SEM model whereby the moderator is predicted by another variable.

If this has been done before, I'd be grateful if anybody could provide any examples.

Many thanks in advance.

p.s. for information purposes all my variables are latent and I am using Mplus to specify my model.

Comment: I think the problem is interpretation - what does it mean to predict a variable that is the product of two variables. It's pretty easy to interpret when you the moderator is the predictor, you solve it by substitution. But (I think) that doesn't work when moderator is an outcome.